# iOS - Eureka validation errors show when I reset form

Tags: ios, swift, validation, reset, eureka-forms

I am getting an error validation message. That is showing up when I press my form's reset button. I think it's because of the `.validatesOnChange`

However, I don't want to take that away because the validation itself is working properly when I try to submit my form. The message pops up if nothing is entered, and if the user enters in something the message goes away.

How do I maintain the validation function while not triggering it when I reset my form? Is there a better way to reset my form? Or better way to make my validation message appear and disappear?

```
@IBAction func resetButtonPressed(_ sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
    form.setValues(["bmi": nil])
    tableView.reloadData()
}

func createForm(){

    LabelRow.defaultCellUpdate = { cell, row in
        cell.contentView.backgroundColor = .red
        cell.textLabel?.textColor = .white
        cell.textLabel?.font = UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 13)
        cell.textLabel?.textAlignment = .right
    }

    form +++ Section("Demographics")

        <<< DecimalRow("bmi") {
            $0.title = "BMI"
            $0.placeholder = "40"
            $0.useFormatterDuringInput = true
            $0.add(rule: RuleRequired())
            $0.validationOptions = .validatesOnChange
            }
            .onRowValidationChanged { cell, row in
                let rowIndex = row.indexPath!.row
                while row.section!.count > rowIndex + 1 && row.section?[rowIndex  + 1] is LabelRow {
                    row.section?.remove(at: rowIndex + 1)
                }
                if !row.isValid {
                    for (index, validationMsg) in row.validationErrors.map({ $0.msg }).enumerated() {
                        let labelRow = LabelRow() {
                            $0.title = validationMsg
                            $0.cell.height = { 30 }
                        }
                        row.section?.insert(labelRow, at: row.indexPath!.row + index + 1)
                    }
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 1):

When you add RuleRequired on a row, after set nil value to the row, and due to .ValidatesOnChange option, you get a validation error. You can do this:

```
@IBAction func resetButtonPressed(_ sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
    form.removeAll()
    createForm()
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the alternative! The `form.removeAll()` created a funky sliding animation so I had to set `UIView.setAnimationsEnabled(false)`. Works great!

Comment: Welcome. in order to get away from animation without workaround you said, you can prepare you createForm() function to return  a Form like this:
`func createForm() -> Form` , then when reset clicked just use `self.form = createForm()`